# Does sudo restrict on which users can acquire superuser privileges?

Tags: sudo

The password which `sudo` asks for is the invoking user's password. So  a user can have superuser prilleges as long as it remembers its own password, which seem very **easy** for any user.

So does sudo  restrict on which users can acquire superuser privileges in that way? If yes, how does it specify that a user can't acquire superuser privileges in that way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` does NOT automatically grant privs if the user password is correct.

It will always request the user password, THEN verify whether it is appropriate for the user to attain privileges (as per the `/etc/sudoers` file as edited by `visudo` by the `root` user).  If the user fails to get privs, it is logged and if configured the administrator gets an email.

This method offers some type of security in that you cannot tell what privs the user has unless the user enters the proper account password.

Thus if the user is NOT in the `sudoers` file then unless the user has the `root` password and uses the `su` command, then the user cannot acquire superuser privs.  There are ways to protect this type of access as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this behavior can be controlled in the file called `/etc/sudoers` on most linux systems. You can add any existing user to that file along with the permissions in specific format. You would need to have `root` user privileges in order to edit this file. For an example, I have configured my `/etc/sudoers` file to include that one specific user does not need to enter the password while gaining superuser privileges:

> user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

On some Linux flavors, there is a `visudo` command available which will open the same file for you to edit.

Comment: Minor quibble: `visudo` is part of [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/) and is available everywhere `sudo` is. `sudo` is also not Linux-specific.

Comment: If the user is not present in `/etc/sudoers`, it will not be allowed to gain superuser access at all when using sudo. Precisely you will see this when a user not present in `/etc/sudoers` tries to gain access: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n558keoa7wb30p5/Screenshot%202018-11-02%2015.05.15.png?dl=0 and this is true for each and every command you run using `sudo`

Comment: Yes, I am asking about how to restrict a user from having superuser privilleges.

Comment: I think I already answered that (unless I am missing some part of the question here); if you don't want a user to gain superuser privileges, don't add that user (or group in which this specific user is) in `/etc/sudoers` file.